# Why is my main activity being called every time my app is opened, even if not fully closed?

Tags: android, android-activity, branch, manifest, branch.io

Every time I open my app, I am being routed through my main activity, rather than returning to the last activity that was previously opened. This only started occurring once I started using **branch.io** for deep-linking functionality. Why might this be happening? I assume that it has something to do with my manifest.. I'll post a snippet:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="roof.android.Application"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoAnimation"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    >

    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_bpzpbF3KFoq5TlSQFp0TdnaauEf6iBuU" />

    <activity
        android:name="roof.android.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="https://roof.app.link/RwKeFhqi5v" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

There are several activities which follow this, but I suppose it is not necessary to post them.

Comment: The issue can be due to `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Comment: I removed this once before and it was still happening @Shaishav

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: looks like you have a mistake when defining your URI scheme:

`<data android:scheme="https://roof.app.link/RwKeFhqi5v" android:host="open" />`

should look more like

`<data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="open" />`

(more about this step in our docs [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/#register-a-uri-scheme)).
You definitely will need to fix that, but I'm not sure if it would be causing the issue you are seeing. Give it a try and if you're still having trouble, I'd suggest [submitting a ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) to our Integrations team so they can take a closer look at the code.